# React JavaScript: Get just "true" checkboxes

Tags: reactjs

I would like to get just the "true" checkboxes, to insert then into a my db.

I have an array of categories:

```
categories_all: [
{
    cat_key: "catfood"
    at_name: "catfood"
    id: 2
    kindof: "food"
    label: "Cat Food"
},
```

ect...
]

I map them in checkboxes:

```
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState({})


  const handleCheckChange = event => {

    setCheckedItems({
      ...checkedItems,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
    })

  }

  return (

          <div>
            {categories_all.map(item => (
              <label key={item.cat_key}>
                {item.label}{" "}
                <Checkbox
                  name={item.id} // I need the id not the name
                  checked={checkedItems[item.id]}
                  value={item.value}
                  onChange={handleCheckChange}
                />{" "}
              </label>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
```

if I console.log(checkedItems) I get this:

```
{2: false, 3: true, 4: true} // this is just the id not the name
```

I would like to get something like:

```
{3, 4}
```

To insert into a table

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the final output you get prior to submitting your form is an `object` that looks like the following:

```js
{ 2: false, 3: true, 4: true }
```

You could use `Object.entries` to iterate through `key/value` pairs inside that object and only return `keys` with values that are `true`:

```js
const formData = {2: false, 3: true, 4: true}

// use `Array.reduce` to iterate through
// object's key/value pairs
const final = Object.entries(formData).reduce(
  (accumulator, entry) => {
    // use destructing assignment to 
    // unpack key & value from an entry
    const [key, value] = entry;
    
    // if `value` is `false`, don't append
    // to the array, otherwise append the key
    if (!value) {
      return accumulator;
    }
    return [...accumulator, parseInt(key, 10)];
  }
, []);

console.log(final);
```

References:

- [Array.reduce() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Object.entries() - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Destructing assignment - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the entries of an object and check if the value is true, your code should look something like that:

```
let items = {2: false, 3: true, 4: true}
let checkedItems = {}; 
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(items)) { 
    if (value === true) checkedItems[key] = key; 
}
console.log(checkedItems); /* {3: "3", 4: "4"} */
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work, I chose another solution

Answer (score 0):

**Do you really need to keep track of unchecked values ?**

If not, you probably need to change the data structure to make `checkedItems` and array containing the names of checked elements :

```
const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState([])

const handleCheckChange = (event) => {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    setCheckedItems((prev) => prev.concat(event.target.name));
  } else {
    setCheckedItems((prev) => prev.filter((current) => current !== event.target.name));
  }
};
```

This way, `checkedItems` only contains `checked` items (seems fair to me) and you can directly send it to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Check boxes aren't meant to have True/false values. When you check a checkbox, it's value is added to the Form collection. Unchecking it removes it.

The right solution is to make the checkbox's value the Id of the thing you want to insert. On the server side, you will only see the selected ID's.

Although a more useful solution is to perform the selected/not selected check on the server to determine which previously selected things you should remove, in addition to which you should add. It's a more complete and robust solution than simply working with fresh inserts.